# How to get the Jquery Autocomplete result event handler to work?

Tags: jquery-plugins, autocomplete, actionresult

I wrote code that fails to use the [JQuery autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) to fire a result function after the user selects something valid (below).

By result, I mean result handler, a function that fires after a good selection happens in the autocomplete plugin.  Documented [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/result#handler).

In my case, I have a form that is really a table where each row is the same, minus the unique ids on the fields: Item1, Qty1, Desc1, then Item2, Qty2, Desc2, and so on.  When the user types in an Item1 code, the Desc1 text should display the English of the item code selected (Item2 -> Desc2, and so on).

I used this code to find all the Item inputs and slap the autocomplete on it.  The result event handler doesn't fire for some reason.  If you notice, I hard coded the "Item1" selection because I haven't figured out how to select the corresponding Desc to the Item where Item1 -> Desc1, Item2 -> Desc2, and so on.

I used the MVC Url.Content only because I happen to get it working.  Someone used Url.Action, which I think is better, just have to figure it out.

Feel free to correct my use as necessary, this is my first time with ASP.NET MVC / JQuery.

Thank you :)

The code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("input[id^='Item']").autocomplete( "<%= Url.Content("~/products/autocomplete")%>", {
  dataType: 'json',
  parse: function(data) {
      var rows = new Array();
      for( var i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
      {   rows[i] = {data:data[i], value:data[i].name, result:data[i].id }; }
      return rows;
  },
  formatItem: function(row, i, n) {
            return row.id + ' - ' + row.name;
        },
  selectFirst: true,
  //autoFill: true,
  minChars: 2,
  max: 30,
  autoFill: true,
  mustMatch: true,
  matchContains: false,
  scrollHeight: 100,
  width: 300,
  cacheLength: 1,
  scroll: true
  });

  $("Item1").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
      $("Desc1").html( !data ? "No match!" : "Selected: " + formatted);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input[id^='Item']").autocomplete( "<%= Url.Content("~/products/autocomplete")%>", {
            dataType: 'json',
            parse: function(data) {
                var rows = new Array();
                for( var i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
                {   rows[i] = {data:data[i], value:data[i].name, result:data[i].id }; }
                return rows;
            },
            formatItem: function(row, i, n) {
                return row.id + ' - ' + row.name;
            },
            selectFirst: true,
            //autoFill: true,
            minChars: 2,
            max: 30,
            autoFill: true,
            mustMatch: true,
            matchContains: false,
            scrollHeight: 100,
            width: 300,
            cacheLength: 1,
            scroll: true
    }).result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        var n = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+/);
        var b = $("span[id='Desc"+n+"']")
        b.html( !data ? "No match!" : "Selected: " + formatted);
    });
});
```

Comment: Good work to show the each property of auto complete textbox.